# Pick of a nested Pick | Typescript

Tags: typescript

We have 2 interfaces: `File` and `User`. 1 `File` has 1 `User`.
We want to pick data from the user and the file.

```
interface DownloadFile {
  id: string
  name: string
  user: User
  createdAt: Date
}

interface User {
  id: string
  name: string
  isEmailValidated: boolean
  unsubscribe: boolean
  email: string
}
```

```
type QueryResponse = {
  file: Pick<DownloadFile, 'id' | 'name'> & {
    user: Pick<DownloadFile['user'], 'id' | 'name' | 'email'>
  }
}
```

This is working fine.

How can we prevent a typo in the nested object name (`userTYPO`) and get an error:

```
type QueryResponse = {
  file: Pick<DownloadFile, 'id' | 'name'> & {
    userTYPO: Pick<DownloadFile['user'], 'id' | 'name' | 'email'>
  }
}
```

Comment: Please remove `pick` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some construct to *constrain* the set of possibilities here. And if you want to constrain a *type* then you must use a generic type with that constraint. That means that this simple snippet:

```
type A = B & C
```

Isn't going to work because there is no way to constrain `B` and `C`.

So what you need is a type that makes this type for you.

There are a lot of ways to do this. Here's one.

```
type MakeFileUserQueryResponseType<
  T extends {
    fileKeys: keyof DownloadFile,
    userKeys: keyof DownloadFile['user'],
  }
> = {
  file: Pick<DownloadFile, T['fileKeys']> & {
    user: Pick<DownloadFile['user'], T['userKeys']>
  }
}
```

Which you would use like so:

```
type QueryResponse = MakeFileUserQueryResponseType<{
  fileKeys: 'id' | 'name',
  userKeys: 'id' | 'name' | 'email'
}>
```

You specifically require a strict type as constraint of `T`, and anything that fails to conform to that will be a type error.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDuIA264AmAYsDigN4BQyywBAXMgM5hSgDm1yIcAthIxZsQnGgFcm0RgFVJULgigQ4kAgEEwjVCoiUAvpUoQAHgAd0UMLXDR4SZLOjIqNOoNYcuPfu+GjaTACivHCkAGpwOHQ6DMgARujoZHAgXGIgTGJxTIrAcQLxicmpNBAhpL6eBoaUYACepigAsnAA1hAkZI5QAIpi0HUAShBM5hkQACoNEAA8XBPIJpAgBEzOXDQwpBAA0hB1TIztdegwaFi4+MTbADQbyBLQewdH+6fn2HiEnRAA2gDkjyg-wAuncaAYAHzIAC860220YAAVgAhWjMMJ8rj8bsgJgCtmRnkxQdCAGTwmgPOTI1HozGXb7bAFA0G4-GAuTE0lcAzVeqNZB9AbDUbocaw5Atdo-brCqBDEZjSRTRozFzIQm7faHZD-Oj-ZAAHz13gg-3B1KeOsY+oIhpN-zNDr1ZVCOH++khQA)

Comment: Thanks! It looks great but a bit overkill